# Unable to connect to SQL server via PowerShell using secure password

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, password-protection

I'm trying to connect to SQL server via PowerShell using the below (I'm new to this). I always get the error "login failed" when I use secure password (from Get-Credential or password stored in file). But if I pass the password as plaintext instead of secure string, it connects successfully. Could any one please suggest a method to pass secure password, ideally stored in an external file.

The code I ran and the error is below:

```
$cred = Get-Credential

$pwd = $cred.Password
$uid = $cred.UserName


$SQLServer = "."
$SQLDBName = "TestDB"


#Initialize connection string
$connString = "Data Source=$SQLServer;Database=$SQLDBName;User ID=$uid;Password=$pwd"

#Create a SQL connection object
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connString

#Attempt to open the connection
$conn.Open()
if($conn.State -eq "Open")
{
    # We have a successful connection here
    # Notify of successful connection
    Write-Host "Test connection successful"
    $conn.Close()
} 


    Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user 'TestUser'."
At line:18 char:1
+ $conn.Open()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

Further details of error from SQL server:

```
Login failed for user 'TestUser'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

Comment: There's no support for `SecureString` in the ADO.NET classes, so you can't get around using a plaintext password in the connection string (`$pwd = cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password`).

Comment: If you don't want to be passing plain text passwords in the Connection String, aim to use a Trusted Connection instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to pass secure string as password by adding **Integrated Security = True;** parameter in connection string.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$pwd = $cred.Password
```

to this

```
$pwd = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

However, I would advise against storing a plain text password in memory like this. Your method requires it to--at best--be passed as a parameter in plain text, so you need a better method.

Try using [this sqlserver module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/21.1.18256) which supports the `-Credential` parameter in the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` function.

Comment: Hi @tonypags,  thank you for the response. I tried using GetNetworkCredential, but got the below error:


Cannot convert the "TestPassword" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".
At line:3 char:1
+ $pwd = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

Comment: `Invoke-Sqlcmd` imitates the behavior of the `sqlcmd` tool and is a poor choice in general for executing arbitrary statements (for starters, there is no support for parameterized statements, encouraging you to use injection-prone string interpolation). It is also no more secure than using `SqlConnection` yourself -- it does not have magic powers, under the covers the secure string is still converted to plain text. The virtual inability to use secure strings securely is why they have been formally deprecated in .NET; PowerShell is stuck with them.

Comment: Oh didn't know that. Probably should have. 
That being said, an easy way to auth would be to run the command as a user with read rights to the DB. 
To your question about the error message, make sure that variable is a pscredential: 
```
$cred | get-member
```

Answer (score 0):

The code did not come from Bing's AI, but the AI gave a nice description:

To create a secure string for connection to SQL Server from PowerShell, you can use the ConvertTo-SecureString cmdlet.
This will create a secure string object that can be used to store the password in a PowerShell script. You can then use this object to create a PSCredential object, which can be used to connect to SQL Server.
You can then use this credential object to connect to SQL Server using the SqlConnection class.
This will create a connection object that uses the specified credentials to connect to SQL Server. You can then use this connection object to execute SQL commands against the database.

```
$cred = Get-Credential

#Initialize connection string
$connString = "Data Source=$SQLServer; Initial Catalog=$SQLDBName"

#Create a SQL connection object
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connString
$conn.Credential = $cred

#Attempt to open the connection
$conn.Open()
if($conn.State -eq "Open")
{
    # We have a successful connection here
    # Notify of successful connection
    Write-Host "Test connection successful"
    $conn.Close()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**